# response.js is not firing at the breakpoints

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I'm just starting out with response.js but it's my understanding from reading the examples that all one needs to do is to add specific data attributes that correspond to the default breakpoints. If that's true why doesn't my simple example work? It stays at the default markup. I think I'm missing something.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="response.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body data-responsejs='{ 
    "create": [{ 
        "prop": "width"
      , "prefix": "min-width- r src"
      , "breakpoints": [0, 320, 481, 641, 961, 1025, 1281] 
  }]
}'>

    <div data-r320="markup @ 320+" data-r961="markup @ 961+">default</div>

    </body>


    </html>
```

Edit:

I don't think the breakpoints are set by default, so I used the json method to create them. It now shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finding the response.js help docs less than clear as well. After lots of trial and error I have the following working ... hope this helps!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Response JS viewport test</title>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body data-responsejs='{
"create": [
    { "prop":"width", "prefix": "min-width-", "lazy":true }
]}'
>

<noscript>no-js</noscript>





<!-- Response.js (ResponseJS.com) uses [0, 320, 481, 641, 961, 1025, 1281] as default  -->


    <div class="min-width" 
         data-min-width-0=" viewport width is 0+"
         data-min-width-320="viewport width is 320+"
         data-min-width-481="viewport width is 481+"
         data-min-width-641="viewport width is 641+"
         data-min-width-961="viewport width is 961+"
         data-min-width-1025="viewport width is 1026+"
         data-min-width-1281="viewport width is 1281+" 

    >
        <strong>fallback</strong> content</div>

   </div>




<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="response.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

---

**EDIT**
Looking at your code again, I have this variation working as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="response.min.js"></script>
</head>

 <body data-responsejs='{ 
    "create": [
        { "prop": "width"
        , "prefix": "min-width-"
        , "lazy": true
        , "breakpoints": [0, 320, 481, 641, 961, 1025, 1281] }
    ]}'
>

<div data-min-width-320="markup @ 320+"
     data-min-width-961="markup @ 961+"
     >
    default</div>

</body>


</html>
```